# Proving that the sum of two finite dimensional subspaces is also finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook that I'm using the sum of two subspaces is defined as

W1 + W2 = {x+y: x is an element of W1 and y is an element of W2}

The information that you're given is that W1 and W2 are finite-dimensional subspaces of vector spaces V and what you're trying to prove is that W1 + W2 must also be finite dimensional.

My thinking was that you can't add two finite things and end up with something infinite but I'm not sure how to go about proving this or even how to start.

Comment: Your intuition about adding finite things is correct, but a finite dimension means that it's spanned by a finite set, so you'd want to show that the sum can be spanned by a finite set, using that fact that the two original spaces are spanned by finite sets.

Comment: What does it mean that a subspace is finite-dimensional? The answer should help you find a proof, since then you know what you need to show.

Comment: Does the definition of being finite-dimensional mean that the dim(V) cannot be infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the map

$$\Phi: W_1\times W_2\to W_1+W_2,\; (w_1,w_2)\mapsto w_1+w_2$$
then prove that $\Phi$ is a surjective linear transformation hence
$$W_1+W_2=\Phi(W_1\times W_2)$$
is a linear space and using the rank-nullity theorem we get that it's finite dimensional space and
$$\dim(W_1+W_2)\le \dim(W_1\times W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2$$

Notice that in the case of the equality of the dimensions, the sum $W_1+W_2$ is called direct.

Answer (score 0):

Show that every element of the sum can be written as a linear combination of the vectors of the Union of the basis of each subspace. That set is finite and generates the sum space.